# change login from google to yahoo

Tags: support, login, google, authentication, yahoo

I hate the idea that I would be at my workplace without actually logging into my **stackoverflow**. I used to login to my stackoverflow account via Google id. But it has been blocked recently(All google sites). But yahoo is still allowed. I would like to login to my account in **SO** via yahoo. Is that possible? Can I change the login from Google to Yahoo?

Comment: Dude. All of Google? Quit. Quit now.

Comment: You can *add* additional logins. Click 'my logins' in your profile, then in that dialog box, click 'add more logins..'

Comment: Now, I thought you would figure out. You use SO right? I meant google authentication... The page in which we are meant to give our cred's is blocked.

Comment: Thanks Martjin. That worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a new Yahoo login by going to your user profile page and clicking on the "my logins" link on the top right (below the Ask Question button).  This will bring up a dialog listing your current logins.  There's an "add more logins..." link on the bottom left of that dialog.  Once you add a new login you can just stop using the old one or remove it.

Comment: Bill you are awesome!!! Thanks.